Call SuiteScript from a ClientScript and a UserEventScript
I have a script that I want to execute when a line from an order is updated and also when the order is saved.
I saved the script on a SuiteLet. When I try to execute the script from the ClientScript, it seems it is not called. I reduced the Suitelet to a log line to check if the flow works.
From the ClientScript, the lines that call the Suitelet is
...
const { body } = https.requestSuitelet({
  scriptId: 'customscript1234',
  deploymentId: 'customdeploy1234',
  body: {
    recordId: currentRecordObj.id,
    recordType: currentRecordObj.type
  }
});
log.debug('response.body: ', body);
...

The Suitelet
/**
 * @NApiVersion 2.1
 * @NScriptType Suitelet
 * @NModuleScope SameAccount
 */

define(['N/log'], (log) => {
  const onRequest = (context) => {
    log.debug({ title: 'START DEBUG' });    
  };
  return { onRequest };
});

The ClientScript works because it executes the code, and the logs are printed. But it seems it doesn't call the Suitelet

Why does it "seem it's not called"?  What are you basing that on? You also mention that the client script logs are printed; if there id a body logged in the client, then the suitelet must be being called.  Have you checked the log level set on the suitelet deployment?  If that's not set to DEBUG, any debug logs will not be generated.

@Krypton, thank you for your comment. I wrote, "It seems it's not called" because the logs are not printed. The response returns HTML.
I changed for a promise with then, and I am getting a 500. Before, without the promise, I had been getting the HTML with a 200.

If there's a response, that means the suitelet is being called.  The HTML being returned may be an error page - check that carefully to parse out any error message which might help - or post it here.

@Krypton, thank you! I am still seeking a solution, but the response is a login page. If I change the Suitlet and I make it AVAILABLE WITHOUT LOGIN, and I change the request to a post using the external URL, it seems to work, but I will look for a solution without making the SuiteLet available without login.

Thank you, @Krypton; your comments led me to find the issue and the solution. However, I will take another approach; in the scenario I am facing, it makes sense to duplicate code rather than having a SuiteLet to avoid repetition.

Glad that helped.  If you were using a suitelet simply to avoid code duplication, it may be appropriate for you to look into using a custom module in a separate file instead.  You would then be able to include (or require) your custom module in whatever scripts you need.
